# PySpark job slows down but runs fast when stopped and re-run

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running PySpark jobs on AWS EMR (EMR 5.19 & Python 2.7).

**Logic:** The job processes several rules one by one, refers to S3 parquet files, creates data frames and creates temporary views in memory which are further referred by subsequent rules via Spark SQL. SQL Output is written to S3.  There are around 1500 rules/sqls to be executed.

**Problem:** While processing around last 100 rules, the process gets stuck at either running the SQL OR writing to S3 and remains there for hours. 
But if I kill the job and re-run from same rule, the same SQL runs quickly, processes same number of records and S3 write is also done quickly and it moves to process next rule.....

**Kindly help me in understanding this behavior - why it runs fast when stopped and re-run but gets stuck when all rules are run together.
 Also let me know if there is something that can be done in the job while its running to make it fast because SQL itself does not seem slow.** 
I tried exploring the logs in EMR (stdout and sterr) but nothing obvious came out. Monitoring also shows CPU & RAM utilization within limits of allocation. I tried logging into individual nodes and checked CPU (via top) and RAM (free -h), all seemed OK.

Cluster is launched with 3 core nodes of type r5.2xlarge (64 GB RAM, 8 cores, 64 GB EBS) and with auto-scaling enabled, it increases to 6 Core nodes and 2 task nodes of above type.

Job is launched via :

```
nohup spark-submit --master yarn  --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.driver.memory=15g 
--conf spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage=false --conf spark.default.parallelism=10 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10 
--executor-memory 15g --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8" 
--py-files s3://bucket-s3/main.py --job apps.MyApp
```

I am writing to S3 from EMR in Parquet to take advantage of EMRFS S3-optimized commeter as per : [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html)

FYI, spark.sql.shuffle.partitions & G1 garbage collector was used to get rid of out-of-memory errors. Also executor memory was earlier 5g and was increased to 15g

Thanks in advance.